# insert new record for date gap in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table :

```
xx_asg

person_no      location        org       mgr_person_no    effective_start_date  eff_end_date    
1               Mumbai        XYZ          101             01-jan-1901          01-jan-1990
1               Mumbai        XYZ          101             01-JAN-1990          31-DEC-4712    
101             Delhi         xyz      201             01-JAN-2005              31-DEC-4712    
5               Delhi         XYZ          1                01-JAN-1901         31-DEC-4712
```

In this table each person has a manager whose person record is also ther in this table.

But as seen above there are cases like for person no 1 with effective start date 01-jan-1901 but it has a manager person no. 101 whose effective start date is from 01-jan-2005. so this is invalid as from 1901-2005 this manager did not existed.

Now i want to insert a record for person_no. 1 in this table in such a way that mgr person np. 101 gets deleted from 01-jan-1901 to 31-dec-2004 and there is a new record for person_no.1 
from 01-jan-2005 to 31-dec-4712

something like :

```
person_no      location        org       mgr_person_no    effective_start_date  eff_end_date    
1               Mumbai        XYZ                            01-jan-1901          01-jan-1990
1               Mumbai        XYZ                       01-JAN-1990              31-DEC-2004
1               Mumbai        XYZ          101             01-JAN-2005         31-DEC-4712   
101             Delhi         xyz      201             01-JAN-2005              31-DEC-4712    
5               Delhi         XYZ          1                01-JAN-1901         31-DEC-4712
```

Comment: Can you please post what you already tried and the problems you are having?

Comment: @Aleksej- i have to make the query any guidance just to the logic will help